# Why is GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the method "FindGameObjectsWithTag" and haven't found a solution that helped yet.

I have 5 active GameObjects in my Scene, tagged with "enemy". I want to get the number of all existing enemies, to display it on the screen. But the following code is not returning any GameObjects:

```
GameObject[] enemys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
```

It should return an array of five GameObjects but there are none. It normally worked fine and there where no problems. I  also tried and tested:

```
GameObject enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy");
```

And it worked, but this method only returns the first GameObject with that tag found. I tried it with another GameObject tagged different and the same problems occurred.

Why does that happen and how can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using the CompareTag method? I can also recommend that you test by comparing with this method.

Comment: Well the possible reasons for [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html?_ga=2.127892877.1438676683.1610207839-1503811403.1600323997) not working are limited: a) your objects are not tagged correctly b) you have a typo in the tag in your code c) your objects are inactive or non-existent at the moment you call it ... It works for everyone else so the problem can't be the method itself but how it is used ;)

Comment: @derHugo But it does work with the other methods, so it should work with that one as well, i guess... Thanks for your response.

Comment: @EdanurAkbas This works! But where is the problem then? Thanks for your answer.